# Correct usage of "reflect"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Is this usage of **reflect** correct?

> He always wears a warm smile.
>   His girlfriend looking at his face all the time started to **reflect** the smile.
>   (= she now wears the same warm smile.)

If this usage is incorrect, is there any verb to replace **reflect**?

Thank you!

Comment: There really is no "correct" or "incorrect" here. "Reflect" is a very creative way to express the thought, and there is nothing wrong with it, but you may not intend to be creative. If you do, _echo_ is another similarly _metaphoric_ usage in English. (But the answer is a matter of opinion, unfortunately.)

Comment: But OP didn't ask what would be *better*, so were in the on-topic realm of synonyms-that-work.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Yes, and that is a vast, unfettered realm that stretches from _adopt_ past _parrot_ and onward past the far-flung Isles of Langerhans.

Comment: @P. E. Dant  You are right.  I don't want to be creative or too literary in the usage of English words.  I would like to sound neutral.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this example it is correct and fairly unambiguous. It is possible to be ambiguous with 'reflect' because it can mean that she has changed in some unspecified way as a result of his smile.

You could also use 'reciprocate' or 'return' if she was specifically smiling back at him or 'copy' or 'imitate' if she was smiling in general at the same things as him.

Comment: Him was smiling?

Comment: @smatterer   Thank your for the answer.  Your suggestions prompted me to ask more questions (these will follow soon).

Answer (score 1):

A verb that would work is **to adopt**, to take as one's own.

> His girlfriend, looking at his face all the time, began to adopt the
>   smile.

Comment: I would say _mimic_ myself, but you type almost as quickly as StoneyB, who must have someone taking fookin _dictation_.

Comment: So, she was mimetic? The girlfriend,not StoneyB's amanuensis.

Comment: Let's say _echoic_ instead, and the fellow can be _narcissistic_.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo  Adopt sounds right.  Adopt sounds suitable to mean what I wanted to mean (which is "Now she always wears the warm smile as he does.").  

I also understand the usage of commas you corrected.  All are very helpful.  Thank you!

Comment: @P.E. Dant: So much responsibility, that's why his head is bowed.

Comment: Those commas are discretionary, especially in fiction/journals.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo I know, but the correction has made the sentence a lot easier to read.